cannot get correct locale via addon event
I set my language to Español - España in Google at https://myaccount.google.com/language?nlr=1&pli=1. However, in my Google Workspace Add-on's event data, the commonEventObject.userLocale field is now returning the short code es instead of the full locale code es-ES, which it used to return previously.
Is this an expected change, or is there a way to ensure userLocale provides the full locale code?
Now the event's locale would be like
{
  userLocale: 'es',
  commonEventObject: {
    userLocale: 'es',
  },
};


Based on this Documentation - https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/concepts/event-objects#common_event_object - This change is not an expected change. Since there is no change in the documentation. I would like to suggest to submit an issue at issuetracker.google.com, so Google Official Support team can provide answers about this change.
